# Microsoft Graph API - multi page user query with $expand failing after updating to latest version

Tags: c#, api, count, microsoft-graph-api, expand

For a while now I had an application built that was syncing employee information between a HR system we use and our AAD to keep titles etc in check

At some point my patch operations to update users started to silently fail (this is another issue..) - but that lead me down the rabbit hole of updating my nuget packages and after that point I am now unable to use my same query to pull all of our users from AAD. I need manager information so I use $expand and I also need to filter so as far as I am aware that means I need to use $count

As it stands because I use $count (there is no @odata.nextlink) when I try to pull the second page of data, the API now tells me $count is not a supported query option (or something along those lines). I've tried removing the query option and other stabs in the dark to no avail.

I've scoured around and cannot find a fix / workaround

Any help would be greatly appreciated - in the end I just need the below info so I can create custom objects I use to compare across systems.

```
 GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = AzureAuth.SetupGraphClient();
            //graphServiceClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";         
            List<Option> queryOptions = new List<Option>();          
            QueryOption count = new QueryOption("$count", "true");
            QueryOption manager = new QueryOption("$expand", "manager($levels=max;$select=id,displayName)");
            queryOptions.Add(count);
            queryOptions.Add(manager);    
            var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request(queryOptions).Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual").Select(x => new
            {
                x.Id,
                x.Department,
                x.Mail,
                x.EmployeeId,
                x.GivenName,
                x.Surname,
                x.Manager,
                x.BusinessPhones,
                x.JobTitle,
                x.AccountEnabled,
                x.DisplayName,
                x.City,
                x.State
            }).Filter($"endsWith(mail, '@sightsciences.com')").GetAsync();

            //Return first paginated result set
            userHolder.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);

            //If more than a single page of data is returned, continue pulling until no further pages are present
            try
            {     
               
                while (users.NextPageRequest != null)
                {                           
                    users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                    userHolder.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

Comment: Check your tags. If they don't mean what you think you might not get attention from the right folks. I swapped your `graph` tag out for the proper one.

Comment: Thanks! I do more lurking then I do posting so tagging isn't a strong point :)